# Using pyquery to try to parse data

Tags: parsing, python-3.x

I am trying to use the following code to pull data from a website.  I am returning a blank screen, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
doc = pq(url='https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/0001047469-15-001377-index.htm')
for heading in doc(".tableFile:contains('Document Format Files')").parent('div'):
    rows = pq(heading).next("tbody tr")
        for row in rows:
            tds = pq(row).find("td")
            print(tds.eq(2).text())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doc = pq(url='https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/0001047469-15-001377-index.htm')
trs = doc('.tableFile').eq(0).find('tr')
for tr in trs:
    td = pq(tr)('td').eq(2)
    print td.text()
```